# Solr remove ranking or modify ranking feature

Tags: lucene, solr, ranking

I want to optimise my Solr engine. I don't want ranked results. I just want all docs which match my query is there any way I can remove it . So that retrieving data improves ?

Comment: Since you selected below answer as correct, can you perhaps change the question? it looks like you were after just retrieving all results, not removing the ranking feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to remove relevancy ranking to achieve what you want.

By setting the `rows` parameter to the same number as the `numfound` you will retrieve all documents matching your query. `http://url-to-some-server/solr/select?q=somequery&rows=200`

if you want the documents sorted in another way than by relevance, just add a `&sort=somefield desc`
where `somefield` is a sortable field.